# how can i set a custom icon dependent on the filename and not extension in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i have installed a new icon theme for vscode called vscode-icnos, and i am trying to
set the todo icon if a file is [todo, TODO, *.todo, *.TODO],

i have done this for the *.todo and *.TODO, but cannot fin a way to set it on the filename, not the extension, any help

*this works in the normal vscode icon seti, but not in my custom*
[image]

[image]

any help

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@chih.hsi.chen/how-to-add-your-custom-icons-to-vscode-icons-9ab8c3f9abc1

Here is shown how to do it step-by-step

Comment: i have found that this is the way how to get the extension to link to an icon, i want the filename to link, not the extension   works for the extensions though

Answer (score 0):

the [link](https://medium.com/@chih.hsi.chen/how-to-add-your-custom-icons-to-vscode-icons-9ab8c3f9abc1) indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68520441/15446311) has indeed the answer

still perhaps not that straightforward, but in my opinion due to the names of `vsicons` parameters

anyway, I already had `.spec` files mapped to the `config` icon, used a `.env` *file* that automatically mapped to the `config` icon, and wanted to map a `.env-secret` file for the same

```
"vsicons.associations.files": [
    {"icon": "config", "extensions": ["spec"], "format": "svg"},
    {"icon": "config", "extensions": [".env-secret"], "filename": true, "format": "svg"}
],
...
```

explanation:

the first `"icon": "config"` is for *all* files with extension `.spec` - other extensions can be added in the list of the `"extensions"` paramenter

in the second `"icon": "config"` I wrote the file name `.env-secret` in... the list of the `"extensions"` parameter, then setting `"filename": true` tells `vsicons` to interpret that *file name* - this is where I think gets confusing

to add *extensions* for the `"icon": "config"`, I can add in the first line

to add *file names* for the `"icon": "config"`, I can add in the second